# Programmatically create a custom product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, programmatically

I have created a custom product. i.e

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="Dome" label="Event Dome Product" modelInstance="Mymodule\Example\Model\Product\Type\EventDome"
          composite="false" isQty="true" canUseQtyDecimals="false" sortOrder="83">
        <priceModel instance="Mymodule\Example\Model\Product\Type\Price"/>
        <customAttributes>
            <attribute name="refundable" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="is_real_product" value="false"/>
            <attribute name="taxable" value="true"/>
        </customAttributes>
    </type>
</config>
```

I now want to programmatically create products. The code below is employed on an admin controller page. It works, however, it does not create a fresh product but overrides the previously created product. i.e if I create a  product and then try and use the same form to create another one it deletes the previous one.

Also, I am unable to set a price.

```
$_product = $this->productFactory->create();


            $_product->setName($array['ProductName']);
            $_product->setTypeId('Dome');
            $_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
            $_product->setSku('test-SKU');
            $_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
            $_product->setVisibility(4);
            $_product->setPrice(array(350));
            $_product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
            $_product->setStockData(array(
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                    'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
                    'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                    'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                    'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                    'qty' => 100 //qty
                    )
                );

            $product = $this->productRepository->save($_product);


            $id = $product->getId();

            return $id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Everyone. I made a silly mistake. The SKU needs to be unique each time

i,e

```
$_product->setSku('test-SKU');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use following code to programmatically create product in magento2.**

```
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
    $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $product->setSku('sku'); // Set your sku here
    $product->setName('Sample Product'); // Name of Product
    $product->setAttributeSetId(4); // Attribute set id
    $product->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
    $product->setWeight(10); // weight of product
    $product->setVisibility(4); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
    $product->setTaxClassId(0); // Tax class id
    $product->setTypeId('simple'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
    $product->setPrice(100); // price of product
    $product->setStockData(
                            array(
                                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                                'manage_stock' => 1,
                                'is_in_stock' => 1,
                                'qty' => 999999999
                            )
                        );
    $product->save();

    // Adding Image to product
    $imagePath = "sample.jpg"; // path of the image
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
    $product->save();

    // Adding Custom option to product
    $options = array(
                    array(
                        "sort_order"    => 1,
                        "title"         => "Custom Option 1",
                        "price_type"    => "fixed",
                        "price"         => "10",
                        "type"          => "field",
                        "is_require"   => 0
                    ),
                    array(
                        "sort_order"    => 2,
                        "title"         => "Custom Option 2",
                        "price_type"    => "fixed",
                        "price"         => "20",
                        "type"          => "field",
                        "is_require"   => 0
                    )
                );
    foreach ($options as $arrayOption) {
        $product->setHasOptions(1);
        $product->getResource()->save($product);
        $option = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')
                        ->setProductId($product->getId())
                        ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
                        ->addData($arrayOption);
        $option->save();
        $product->addOption($option);
    }
```